# Diffusion Command Line Repository Import

Tags: phabricator

I want to be able to import new (git) repositories into my diffusion repository from the command line.  I checked './repository --help' and didn't see any relevant command line arguments.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/repository.create/ worked well enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/repository.create/ was what I wanted.  Posting extra text so I can answer the question and close the task.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. To file a feature request, see this document:

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/feature_requests/

Comment: Thanks Evan.  Is there anyone I should tag in the initial task?